# Boto3 + DynamoDB: Query all data with limit and order by

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

What I am trying to achieve is to be able to get 15 records for each page using limit and ordered by the range key. This is my table format.

```
Primary partition key: id (string) -> in GUID format
Primary sort key: created_on (number) -> date stored in epoch format
```

My problem is I am not able to do this

```
client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = client.Table('my_table')
result = table.query(Limit=15, ScanIndexForward=False)
```

I am getting this error, which is pretty understandable

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: 
Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request
```

Now my problem is that I do not want to filter out the result by `id` and just have all data sorted by `created_on` and get the first 15 records, which is not possible on `query()` since it has a mandatory `equals to` on the primary partition key.

Using `scan()` I am not able to use `ScanIndexForward` which sorts the date in descending order.

Your thoughts are very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to order the results of `scan`.
More over, `scan` doesn't retrieve all your record, max it can get 1MB of data.
You need to repeat the process using `LastEvaluatedKey` and then perform sorting in your code.